# Padding and overflow scroll in Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, padding, microsoft-edge

What I desire is for `.wrapper` to have 76px of `padding` at the bottom of the element. Why isn't `.wrapper`'s `padding-bottom` property respected in Microsoft Edge?

Is there a fix for this that does not involve `margin` on the last child?

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-bottom: 76px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20624938/padding-bottom-is-ignored-in-firefox-and-ie-on-overflowing-elements-with-no-cont

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a Microsoft Edge issue alone, Firefox has the same [issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=748518)

As a workaround, give the `padding-bottom` in the child container.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper_inner {
  padding-bottom: 76px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper_inner">
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
    <div class="wrapper__thing">Test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```