# Firefox ignores padding when using overflow:scroll

Tags: css, firefox

When using `overflow: scroll` combined with `padding: /* ... */` CSS property, the padding at the bottom of the element is missing in Firefox. (But works in Chrome and Safari.)

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 50px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

ul,
li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>padding above first line in every Browser</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>no padding after last line in Firefox</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[View Demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/iAMHoGvSE4r0gEpS3dj7/preview)

Did I missed something or is there any kind of work around for this issue?

---

*Notice: the demo doesn't use any library for normalizing, but I tried `normalize.css` too, but without success.*

Comment: W3C has to resolve this issue, hopefully they'll choose the behavior of Chrome!
https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/129

Comment: This bug seems to be resolved in the latest Firefox (currently v89)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> in Firefox padding-bottom is ignored with overflow:auto or
>   overflow:scroll, see the documentation
>
> https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=748518

still if you want to work around your example to achieve the desired result then see the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nileshmahaja/4vuaf4o3/1/

**Modified CSS**

```
.container {
    height: 200px;
    padding: 50px 50px 0;
    border: solid 1px red;
    overflow-y:auto;
    display:block;
}
ul{
    padding:0 0 50px;
    display:block
}
li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the link to their bug tracker. It's a pity that common browser handle that different. However I guess I will need to live with.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - really helpful. I've posted an alternative workaround using :last-child and margin which I find useful.

Answer (score 56):

After a bit of brainstorming with fellow developers, although not very graceful, this pure css solution works:

```
.container:after {
    content: "";
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
}
```

#### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4vuaf4o3/83/)

Comment: This worked for me, genius! You can also set a "safety" opacity: 0 just to be sure.

Comment: This worked for me but needed a `width: 100%` to work.

Comment: Worked great for me. Note that if the parent `.container` has `display: flex;` you may need to add `flex-shrink: 0` to this `::after` pseudo element so it doesn't get shrunk into nothingness.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not a fan of creating additional DOM elements to work around displaying issues, however it seems to help to split up the element into two elements like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-inner">
        <!-- long content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

and then assigning `overflow: scroll` to the outer element and add `padding: /* ... */` to the inner element.

Comment: This still has the same problem.

Comment: adding an inner div with padding worked for me with Firefox 66.

Answer (score 5):

I ended up achieving the same effect (space between last item in a scrollable container and the end of container) in a slightly different way:

```
.container :last-child {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Perhaps there are technical differences between what's really going on, but I find this pretty effective.

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saml0w/btcm7uwr/)

Answer (score 4):

You could target Firefox browsers and add extra margin to the element being scrolled:

```css
@supports (-moz-appearance:none) {

  ul {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
}
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports):

> The @supports CSS at-rule lets you specify declarations that depend on a browser's support for one or more specific CSS features.

By requesting support for a Firefox specific rule, you're effectively targeting the Firefox browser.

Answer (score 2):

I think `@-moz-document url-prefix()` is the feasible solution.

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 50px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

ul,
li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .container > :last-child {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>padding above first line in every Browser</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>no padding after last line in Firefox</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Arthurion's answer in all cases, such as following an `input` or `img` element. You can instead create a spacer element such as a `div` and place it at the end of the scrolled content:

```
.spacer-1rem {
    content: "";
    height: 1rem;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though what worked for me was similar to other proposed answers, these other answers didn't work for me.

What did work was the following:

```
.container::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    padding: calc(var(--desiredPadding) / 2);
}
```

which means:

- for me it was necessary to use `padding` on the pseudo-element. Using `padding-bottom` didn't work, nor did `height`
- I needed to divide padding by 2, as a consequence
- It was necessary to specify `display: block`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I changed the padding for a border with color transparent. Since I use `box-sizing: border box`  this will not mislead to problems with width and height