# Flexbox padding bottom fails in Firefox and Safari

Tags: css, flexbox

When scrolling down the `.parent` div you should see its red background at the bottom due to the `padding-bottom`. This works in Chrome, but not in Safari and Firefox.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: red;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 1;
}

.child {
  flex: 1 0 100px;
  background: green;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
   child
  </div>
  <div class="child">
   child
  </div>
  <div class="child">
   child
  </div>
  <div class="child">
   child
  </div>
  <div class="child">
   child
  </div>
  <div class="child">
   child
  </div>
  <div class="child">
   child
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpvJPY

Edit: This question is different from the proposed duplicate because it regards a problem with a fixed padding in pixels, as opposed to the percentage padding in the duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Padding-bottom/top in flexbox layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23717953/padding-bottom-top-in-flexbox-layout)

Comment: I think it is different because the padding value in my case is not a percentage but a fixed one in pixel units.

Comment: if you change the display of the parent element to `display: table` it works, in FireFox. :D

Comment: In my case it happened only in Firefox, because of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986977/firefox-ignores-padding-when-using-overflowscroll

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why the `padding-bottom` fails in Firefox and Safari. It may have something to do with the container being [*over-constrained*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38997047/3597276). But that's just a guess.

What I am more certain about, however, is a reliable, cross-browser solution. Pseudo-elements on a flex container are rendered as flex items. So instead of `padding` use `::before` and `::after`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: red;
  /* padding-top: 20px; */
  /* padding-bottom: 20px; */
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 1;
}

/* NEW */
.parent::before,
.parent::after {
  flex: 0 0 20px;
  content: '';
}

.child {
  flex: 1 0 100px;
  background: green;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">child</div>
    <div class="child">child</div>
    <div class="child">child</div>
    <div class="child">child</div>
    <div class="child">child</div>
    <div class="child">child</div>
    <div class="child">child</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWrJqb?editors=1100)