# padding bottom not working in firefox & IE11

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox, cross-browser

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xkkc1paq/)

**CSS**

```
body, html {
  background: violet
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
.fixed {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  background: #fff;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
}
.container {
      -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 30px 60px;
}
.footer {
  border-top: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 35px;
  background: red
}
```

I have tried this above code in both **Chrome** & **Firefox** browser. I have attached two screenshots also. I want to know why **padding-bottom:60px** is not working in Firefox. But, its working fine in Chrome browser. Also not working in IE11

**In Chrome Browser (Working Fine) :**

[image]

**In Firefox Browser (Padding Bottom not working. WHY?) :**

[image]

Really I don't understand this..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox ignores padding when using overflow:scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986977/firefox-ignores-padding-when-using-overflowscroll)

Comment: just have an inner container and put your padding on that - https://jsfiddle.net/xkkc1paq/7/

Comment: It's good @Pete. But, why it doesn't work in Parent div container?

Comment: Nuances of css each browser interprets it in a different way, it's about finding the easiest way to make it behave in the same way in all browsers, bar IE and safari, in which case I punish those stupid users with a bit less niceness!

Comment: I know this is an old post, but can anyone else confirm this bug is resolved in the latest Firefox v89? I tested the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkkc1paq/) in both Chrome and Firefox and it seems to work the same.

Comment: @kimbaudi Yes. I think it is working fine in latest Firefox v89..

Answer (score 15):

There are alot of reasons told by alot of experts like overflow property causes this or display:flex handles padding a bit differently if you search for a reason. @Temani Afif is correct and corrected me as well and here is a recent bug noted with the `overflow-y:scroll` or `overflow-y:auto` not taking padding-bottom into account.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1417667

For a quick solution what you can do is instead of applying the bottom padding on the flex item which has the overflow-y property set, apply it on the item's pseudo element of after e.g.

```
.container {
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 30px 60px 0 60px;
}

.container:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  padding-bottom:30px;
}
```

Hope this helps you and all others out.

Comment: read the other question again, it's related to % values and no fixed values so this is not the reason ...the reason is the scroll, check above link in comment

Comment: by the way it's not logic at all as fixed value are fixed so 1px is always 1px in all the browser so all of them will behave the same ... it's not about complex calculation, rouding or % values

Comment: Ok then what do you think is the solution. Even if its percentage. FF still ignores the bottom margin.

Comment: I'm sure display:flex won't affect padding-bottom @NasirT

Comment: @Karuppiah. Then explain to me why the padding bottom is being ignored. Want to double check. Remove the display:flex from the jsfiddle in the question in the .fixed class and see what happens in FF.

Comment: Simply read the link i shared and you will understand ... there is diffferent behavior between browser due to the scroll

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986977/firefox-ignores-padding-when-using-overflowscroll

Comment: @NasirT I have tried this without flex concept. I'm sure flex won't affect this padding in firefox. Thats why I'm posted here why padding-bottom is ignore in firefox. I don't know too man...

Comment: @Karuppiah did you also check the link i share ... no need to think more, everything is explained there

Comment: I have changed my answer with a recent bug link and Thanks Temani Afif and Karuppiah for making me see the reason properly and understand it. This was a very good question.

Comment: Had this issue with flex/overflow-y/padding-bottom in IE11. Great fix. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This occurs because the `overflow-y: auto;` rule. Try this CSS

```
.container {
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;  /* This rule affect the padding-bottom, quit it and see the results */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 30px 60px;
}
.footer {
  border-top: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 35px;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 60px; /* This rule add the effect you want */
}
```

## EDIT

Theoretically the padding-bottom is there, but when you apply an `overflow-y:auto;` the scroll bar occupate all space available.

If you don't want add a `margin-top: 60px;` you can try this new CSS:

```
.container {
      -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container p {
    padding: 30px 60px;
}
.footer {
  border-top: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 35px;
  background: red;
}
```

## UPDATE

Or try this solution:

```
.container {
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 30px 60px;
}
.container p {
    padding: 0 0 60px 0;
}
```

Comment: `This rule affect the padding-bottom, quit it and see the results` can you explain why ?

Comment: I don't want to add margin-top:60px; I need padding-bottom:60px want to work. And Definitely I need overflow-y: auto

Comment: No No No. I want to add padding-bottom: 60px in container class only. Not in p tag.

Comment: `but when you apply an overflow-y:auto; the scroll bar occupate all space available.` this is false ... check the link i shared above and you will see that this is a behavior of FF related to scroll with padding

Comment: @TemaniAfif Maybe the explanation is not totally right, but the sense is the same. It is not necessary to overmind with much theory. BTW the link you've shared, expose the same thing you've asked in the firts comment of my answer, it demostrate that my answer is not wrong at all. And please, if you know the solution, share it with the community, it will help many people.

Comment: no need to answer a question already answered that's why we have the duplicate ;) everything is explained well in this question